# Get current index model in itemDelegate

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm working with [this code](https://github.com/hvoigt/qt-qml-treeview) and I'm trying to get the number of rows or if the selected item has or not children. But I'm getting a weird behavior.

I added the next code to the qml:

```
    itemDelegate: Item {
        CheckBox {
            id: checkbox
            text: styleData.value.text
            checked:false
            visible: styleData.value === undefined ? false : true

            onClicked: {
                theModel.print(styleData.row, styleData.column,
                               theModel.index)
                theModel.print(styleData.row, styleData.column,
                               theModel.index(styleData.row,
                                              styleData.column,
                                              theModel.currentIndex))
            }
        }
    }
```

And my model (treemodel.cpp) has the following method:

```
bool TreeModel::print(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &modelIndex)
{
    createIndex(row, column, 1);

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << " row: " << row
             << " column: " << column
             << " rowCount (a): " << this->rowCount(index(row, column, modelIndex))
             << " rowCount (b): " << this->rowCount(modelIndex)
             << " hasChildren (a): " << this->hasChildren(index(row, column, modelIndex))
             << " hasChildren (b): " << this->hasChildren(modelIndex);

    return true;
}
```

When I click on the checkboxes, sometimes the number of rows is right but the most of times is wrong. I.e. `rowCount` is not returning 0 when I click a row without children or 6 when we only have 4 children.

`rowCount` works fine. It returns always the right value when we're expanding the tree using the arrows so I suppose the problem is how I'm passing the index to the `print` method.

Comment: If `theModel` is a `TreeModel`, the `theModel.index` and `theModel.currentIndex` do not exist. All you have is a `TreeModel::index()` but it is not exposed to QML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#itemDelegate-prop) you can retrieve the current index in the `itemDelegate` with `styleData.index`.

This should work as expected :

```
itemDelegate: Item {
    CheckBox {
        id: checkbox
        text: styleData.value.text
        checked:false
        visible: styleData.value === undefined ? false : true

        onClicked: {
            theModel.print(styleData.row, styleData.column,
                           styleData.index)
        }
    }
}
```